# Django queryset - Isn’t it possible to filter on a FloatField?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I’m trying to do a very simple operation but I get an issue.
I have a simple model :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=False)
    value = models.FloatField(null=True)
    interval = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

My goal is to get the MyModel object with the biggest value.

```
#Get the value
value = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gte=’2014-05-01’, date__lte=’2014-05-31’).aggregate(Max(‘value’))[‘value__max’]

# Get the object corresponding to the max value
my_object = MyModel.objects.get(value=value)
```

This code raise me an error : “matching query does not exist” …
I tried to hardcode a value (that exists), I have the same error.

Am I doing something wrong ? Isn’t it possible to filter on a FloatField ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is with the way floating point numbers are represented in Python (Django's `FloatField` maps to Python's `float` and Django's `DecimalField` maps to Python's `decimal`; see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#floatfield-vs-decimalfield)).

The difference is that `float`s are not precise because of the way they are represented on your computer, the `decimal` type aims to remedy some of these issues that arise through that (have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for it, they explain that very well).

Now given your case of trying to fetch a `float` via an exact match you can try 2 things:

1. Change the type of `value` on `MyModel` to a [`DecimalField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) (i.e. `value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, null=True)`)
2. If you want to keep the type as a `FloatField` you can try to query a range of values, however you might end up with more than 1 result (so `MyModel.objects.get()` might throw an exception, complaining that the query returned more than 1 result): `MyModel.objects.filter(value__range=(1.23, 1.24))` or  `MyModel.objects.filter(value__gte=1.23, value__lt=1.24)`

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to get the object with the largest value would be to order it and take the first:

```
value = MyModel.objects.filter(date__gte='2014-05-01', date__lte='2014-05-31').order_by('-value')[0]
```

That has the advantage that it's a single query rather than 2, and doesn't incur an expensive aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for your advise ! You are right, i will change that.
But I still can't understand why a simple filter on a floatfield don't work.

Answer (score 1):

`date` field `DateTimeField`, but the code is passing strings. Specify `datetime.date` instead:

```
import datetime

...

value = MyModel.objects.filter(
    date__gte=datetime.date(2014, 5, 1),
    date__lte=datetime.date(2014, 5, 31)
).aggregate(Max('value'))['value__max']
```

Comment: Thank you for the advise! But the problem don't come from this part of the code, the main problem is in the MyModel.objects.get(value=value). It can't find the object even if it exists.