# True Django ORM returns empty result

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two model classes, each containing following info.

**Model A**

```
latitude = models.FloatField()
longitude = models.FloatField()
```

**Model B**

```
latitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
longitude = models.FloatField(null=True)
```

Now I want to filter something from model B with

```
ModelB.objects.filter(latitude=model_a_obj.latitude, longitude=model_a_obj.longitude)
```

which returns an empty QuerySet.

The latitudes and longitudes are existing though. Because, when I do this to get the model B object

```
ModelB.objects.filter(some_string_field="String I know by hand")[0].latitude == model_a_obj.latitude
```

it returns `True`, for `longitude` as well `True`.

So, why does the filter method from above return an empty result?

Comment: Your are more likely to get an answer if you provide a minimum example (i.e., provide the data to insert into the DB). With the information you provide, I don't see any obvious errors.  Exact float comparisons can be nasty in some cases, though.

Comment: It is a general problem with float point precision and a fiter by `FloatField`. Possible duplicate of [Django queryset - Isn’t it possible to filter on a FloatField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016752/django-queryset-isn-t-it-possible-to-filter-on-a-floatfield)